# Typescript: where to put a function related to an interface

Tags: typescript

Suppose I'm using this trivial interface:

```
interface Number {
  n: number
}
```

Any plain object like `{n: 1}` implements that interface, and the interface with plain objects are very convenient for typing for example a redux store, a payload data for an http request/response, and so on.

Now, suppose that I need a function, `getDouble`, which is strictly related to `Number`, because I want to do some calculations with plain objects implementing that interface, i.e.:

```
const number = await someHttpClient.get('url').response as Number;
console.log(number.getDouble());
```

Clearly I cannot do that, since I cannot implement the `getDouble` inside the interface.
I could declare that function somewhere else, like:

`const getDouble = (number: Number) => number * 2;`

but then it would not be a function related to `Number` but just an external function.

I should then convert `Number` to a class. That would work of course, but then every time I would have an instance of that class to deal with and NOT a plain object, so I could not simply assign a plain object to a variable of the type of that class, I should do an heavy refactoring, and I would also have problems like that instances of classes should not be present in a redux store, and so on.

So how should these kind of issues (the need of having methods related to interfaces) be dealt with in a clean way without heavy modification to the code structure?

Comment: Aside: `Number` is already the name of an [existing JS class constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) and the related [TS interface](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/6bef0cb0c4e4bf3962d3cace7a72278431bac4e0/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L542) so you might want to change the name you use here to avoid confusion.

Comment: (I will use `MyNumber` to talk about your type.) Can you explain what "related" means to you?  A function whose signature is `(n: MyNumber)=>number` is *related* to `MyNumber`, despite being an external function. If by "related" you mean "exists as a method on a `MyNumber` object" then yeah, anything you do is going to require jumping through some hoops. `class` is an easy way to do it but you could get it to happen with "plain" objects too, since such objects can have function-valued properties. If you don't mean "must be a method" then maybe `namespace` or `module` packaging could help you?

Comment: See [this](https://tsplay.dev/4WyV2w) for more info.  The top solution `Namespace` packages `getDouble` in possibly a more natural way for you?  Or you could use the two method solutions below that, where you can convert a `RawNumber` (an object with just an `n` property) to and from a `MyNumber` (an object with the extra methods you want).  Let me know if any of that works for you and I'll write up an answer if so.  Good luck!

Comment: Personally I would declare the function somewhere else, like you have written here.  I don't see what's so wrong with `console.log(getDouble(number));`.  If it's a `class`, you would have to call the constructor before using a method on your API data.  `console.log((new MyNumber(number).getDouble())`.